# Why is the database connection lost on every query?

Tags: postgis, database, error

Every time I started a query the connection with the database is lost. Anyone familiar with this problem?

This problem occurs with various query, for instance:

```
CREATE TABLE table
SELECT a.*, b.column, b.column 
FROM table_a a JOIN table b 
ON ST_intersects (a.geom, b.the_geom)
WHERE st_IsValid (a.geom);
```

I just updated from postgis 1.5.3 to 1.5.5 but that doesn't seem to help.

Anyone an idea?

---

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem.

There was something wrong with the topology of one of the layers. After editing the query worked without disconnecting.

I find it rather strange that the program and service crashes when the topology is not correct. Can someone shed a light on this issue.

Comment: As noted below in the comments, the backend should never crash. If it's crashing on you that's a bug that we need to fix. Can you share the data that makes this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you want to create a table before querying it? Try just this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM table_a a JOIN table_b b
ON ST_Intersects (a.geom, b.the_geom)
WHERE ST_IsValid (a.geom);
```

Otherwise go to the postgres.log and see if there are any errors reported and update your question according the log file.

Make sure that you select the proper columns. I guess `b.column` is not existent. Furthermore you were selecting it twice.

Comment: Yes I am sure I want to create a new table. I wasn't selecting it twice, the b.column statement was meant as an example :).

Comment: Then you should use the proper syntax in the future. You also should avoid to post examples which apparently do not work due to these obvious errors. I'm glad that you solved your problem anyway.

Comment: Thanks for you advice, next time I will write a more useful example :)

But isn't it strange that when I use the wrong syntax that the connection is lost. Normally postgres/postgis just gives an error, and from that error I can improve my syntax.

Comment: Sadly I don't have postgis installed here and I don't have the "corrupted" data you had. But mostly it depends on the configuration of your system and where the error occurs. If it is deep inside of postgis it is sometimes hard to use the postgres internal structures to catch the exception and then the database crashes. So you may found a bug :)

Comment: The database shouldn't crash ever. If you can find the pairing of geometries that caused the crash, or can even just share the tables, please put them on a ticket on the PostGIS issue tracker. http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis